# Recover screen buffer after shutdown

Tags: linux, unix, gnu, gnu-screen

I had a screen session running a process could take days to complete.  There was a cooling failure in the server room and the machines were shutdown, and now rebooted.  Is there a way to recover my screen buffers?  I know the processes will be terminated etc. But I would like to see the output and try to salvage some of the work.  Certainly that was buffered somewhere (although maybe it's been cleaned up by now?).

In the future if I know that I want to see / save output to the screen, what's the best way to do that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `screen`'s task is not to log the output of the terminal.  You should have used sth like `script` if you wanted that.  There might be a function within `screen` to achieve a similar goal, but I'd be surprised and a bit concerned if `screen` would do that without my asking for it.  After all it would probably mean to store private data.

Comment: I was just hoping if I hadn't run it again there was a buffer somewhere I might find. The final output of my programs is of course being kept elsewhere, but when they were terminated mid-run I was hoping to find out where they left off.  **duskwuff** below offers a good explanation and what I _should have_ done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`screen` stores scrollback buffers in memory, not on disk. As such, there's no way to recover them from a process that is no longer running. (While there is a faint possibility that the buffers were swapped out to disk, identifying and recovering them will be extremely difficult.)

If the output of a process is important, have it written to disk, either by piping the process through `tee`, or by enabling logging on the `screen` tab it's on (using the [`log`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Log.html) command, mapped to <kbd>^A</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> by default).

Comment: Thanks. and bummer! I was really hoping it was buffered to a temp file or something.  I'll definitely pay attention to logging in the future.    So deflog can be used to turn logging on by default? Do you know if this setting is persistent to restarts or just to one "running" of screen?

Comment: None of the options in GNU screen are sticky. Write a `.screenrc` if you want to make settings applied by default.

Comment: @duskwuff can you provide a reference (docs / code) which confirms that scrollback buffer is stored by `screen` in memory? Do you know if there are limits, over which if flushes to disk?

Comment: The screen manual doesn't really talk about the internals of the application much; I don't think it _explicitly_ says anywhere that scrollback is stored in memory. There is definitely no provision for storing scrollback on disk, though.

Comment: Some of the code involved with scrollback is in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/resize.c -- the screen source code is a mess, though, so I can't really point to anything more specific. Hopefully this helps answer your question, @tutuDajuju?